# NSSet intersectsSet implementation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

I need to to make a method to compare some NSSet and see if all the objects are there or if it is missing an object and which object is it. 
I just made on the viewDidLoad method, but I need a method which will check all the NSSet (there are a lot). What I did not work so well.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];
         NSMutableSet *masterSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4" ,nil];
        NSMutableSet *set2 = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
        NSMutableSet *set3 = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"2", @"10", @"12", @"14", @"18", nil];

        if ([masterSet intersectsSet:set2] == [set2 count]) {
            NSLog(@"set2: %@", set2);
        }
}
```

In this example I try to check, If all the object on set2 are in masterSet, so I print set2. I don't understand why this is not working, because this is not printing on the log.

If some one can help me, I need to make this "If" on a method that will check all the NSset I have, and to check if there is missing one object to full match, get this object too.
Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

`intersectsSet:` returns a `BOOL`.  That means 0 (false) or 1 (true).  So as long as your count on set2 is larger than 1 that statement can never be true.

The method you are looking for is [intersectSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableSet/intersectSet%3a):

Comment: Thank you for your help, I saw the methods from your link and this is what I need, I will try it. If you have any explame for those methad could be great, If not It's ok anyway, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you want to know if every object in `masterSet` are in `set2`.

you can check this with `isEqualToSet:`

```
if ([masterSet isEqualToSet:set2]) {
    NSLog(@"set2: %@", set2);
}
```

> From the docs:
>   **Returns**    YES if the contents of otherSet are equal to the contents of the receiving set, otherwise NO.
>
> Two sets have equal contents if they each have the same number of
>   members and if each member of one set is present in the other.

Comment: Thank you for answer, is good what you said, I think I need to implement this into one of this methods  - (void)intersectSet:(NSSet *)otherSet   - (void)minusSet:(NSSet *)otherSet   - (void)unionSet:(NSSet *)otherSet Do you have any example for those methods.

Comment: You do know the [NSSet Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  and the [NSMutableSet Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableSet)? There you'll find all the methods you asked for.

Comment: Yes, I know, thank you, I just wanted an example, there is not there, but is ok. Thank you